# subtract div text from input

Tags: jquery, input

I have a div block with text inside:

```
<div>hello</div>
```

I have an input text field whose last entry is always the text inside the div.  For example,

```
<input type="text"></input> with the user inputed text as "bob, james, hello"
```

On click with jquery, how can I make the text inside the div be subtracted from the string inside the input, leaving the input as:

```
<input type="text"></input> text as "bob, james,"
```

Comment: input doesnt have closing tag!! you cant write between tags!!

Comment: i know I just displayed it this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is off a litte:

```
<div>hello</div>
<input type="text" value="bob, james, hello" />
```

JQuery:

```
$('div').click(function(){
    var _text = $('input[type=text]');
    _text.val(_text.val().replace($(this).html(),''));
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/kCWtr/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$('div').click(function(){
    var inputElem=$('input[type=text]'), arrText=inputElem.val().split(/,\s*/g), indexElemToRemove=arrText.indexOf($(this).val());
    if(indexElemToRemove>-1) arrText.splice(indexElemToRemove,1);
    inputElem.val(arrText.join(', '));
});
```